# Bytecode instrumentation system classes in Java with ASM

Tags: java

My javaagent, run via -javagent, instruments classes with callbacks to static methods on one of my classes.  This works great, apart from on system classes, e.g. java/lang, java/util, which throw ClassDefNotFounderror at the point when the method is called (with INVOKESTATIC).  So it appears they are instrumented, because the method call is attempted, but have an access or visibility issue that my user classes don't have.  My callback class and its methods are all public.

I've tried adding my class to the classpath (instead of just loading via -javaagent) but that didn't help.  Is there some protection of system classes I need to override?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're explicitly looking for classes to instrument.  Why aren't you using `java.lang.instrument` to intercept classes that are being loaded when the target JVM executes?  See this [example](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19309.html)

Can you paste your code, or the relevant parts?